# Requesting advice diagnosing a R710 running xen on Debian Stretch panicking

Tags: linux, networking, debian, virtual-machine, virtualization

I am requesting advice diagnosing a R710 running xen on Debian Stretch panicking once a day.

The server will run fine for ~24h and eventually throw a Kernel Panic usually about bxn2. (Will put full panic below) System no longer responds and usually requires a reboot. After the reboot the system is fine but will eventually panic.

I have an identical server running server which does not crash when it has one or two vm's but will crash when all vms are run from the system. I also have another R710 with a H700 which is running ~10 vms without issue.

I am also having issues recreating the panic. At one point I was able to reliably crash the second server by loading the cpu to max and doing high IO. (sha1sum /dev/zero and dd).

The Dell R710 specs are as follows:

- 2x 4core cpu
- 72GB of ram
- SAS 6/iR Integrated Firmware Version : 00.25.47.00.06.22.03.00
- SAS6 passing through to 1x 1tb os disk, 2x 2tb disk in mdadm array (03:00.0 SCSI storage controller: LSI Logic / Symbios Logic SAS1068E PCI-Express Fusion-MPT SAS (rev 08))
- Broadcom NetExtreeme 2 nic. (01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Limited NetXtreme II BCM5709 Gigabit Ethernet (rev 20))
- All bios and firmware updated with lifecycle controller.

It is running Debian Stretch with the following details:

- GNU/Linux 9 \n \l
- Linux xen01 4.9.0-3-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.30-2+deb9u3 (2017-08-06) x86_64 GNU/Linux
- It is running xen-hypervisor-4.8-amd64 4.8.1-1+deb9u1 with 22 virtual machines.
- ii  firmware-bnx2                  20161130-3                   all          Binary firmware for Broadcom NetXtremeII
- mptsas version 3.04.20
- mpt3sas version 13.100.00.00
- ii  bridge-utils                   1.5-13                       amd64        Utilities for configuring the Linux Ethernet bridge

So far I have tried the following (alone and in different combinations):

- Disable MSIX for bnx2. modprobe bnx2 disable_msi=1
- Disable MSIX for mpt3sas. modprobe mpt3sas msix_disable=1
- Added intremap=off to kernel and turned off Intel Virtualization via BIOS to avoid Intel 55x0 Chipset errata. https://support.citrix.com/article/CTX136517
- Lowered vm.dirty_background_ratio=5 and vm.dirty_ratio=10 to get around Linux Server Crashing with "INFO: task blocked for more than 120 seconds"
- Set nic rx higher and raised net.core.netdev_max_backlog=30000 as per https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37727/solving-ethernet-watchdog-timer-deadlocks

One example of a panic.

```
Aug 18 14:45:16 xen02 kernel: [54277.859415] ------------[ cut here ]------------
Aug 18 14:45:16 xen02 kernel: [54277.859451] WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 0 at /build/linux-me40Ry/linux-4.9.30/net/sched/sch_generic.c:316 dev_watchdog+0x22d/0x230
Aug 18 14:45:16 xen02 kernel: [54277.859456] NETDEV WATCHDOG: eno2 (bnx2): transmit queue 5 timed out
Aug 18 14:45:16 xen02 kernel: [54277.859457] Modules linked in: ipmi_si xt_tcpudp xt_physdev br_netfilter iptable_filter xen_netback xen_blkback mpt3sas raid_class mptctl bridge stp llc dell_rbu xen_gntdev xen_evtchn xenfs xen_privcmd ipmi_devintf iTCO_wdt iTCO_vendor_support evdev joydev mgag200 ttm drm_kms_helper intel_powerclamp coretemp drm i2c_algo_bit serio_raw dcdbas sg pcspkr acpi_power_meter ipmi_msghandler wmi button shpchp i7core_edac lpc_ich mfd_core edac_core ip_tables x_tables autofs4 ext4 crc16 jbd2 fscrypto ecb glue_helper lrw gf128mul ablk_helper cryptd aes_x86_64 mbcache raid10 raid456 async_raid6_recov async_memcpy async_pq async_xor async_tx xor raid6_pq libcrc32c crc32c_generic raid0 multipath linear dm_mod raid1 md_mod sd_mod uas usb_storage sr_mod cdrom ata_generic hid_generic usbhid hid crc32c_intel psmouse
Aug 18 14:45:16 xen02 kernel: [54277.859517]  ehci_pci uhci_hcd mptsas ehci_hcd ata_piix scsi_transport_sas mptscsih libata mptbase usbcore usb_common scsi_mod bnx2 [last unloaded: ipmi_si]
Aug 18 14:45:16 xen02 kernel: [54277.859533] CPU: 0 PID: 0 Comm: swapper/0 Not tainted 4.9.0-3-amd64 #1 Debian 4.9.30-2+deb9u3
Aug 18 14:45:16 xen02 kernel: [54277.859534] Hardware name: Dell Inc. PowerEdge R710/0YDJK3, BIOS 6.4.0 07/23/2013
Aug 18 14:45:16 xen02 kernel: [54277.859537]  0000000000000000 ffffffff81328574 ffff8811f5a03e20 0000000000000000
Aug 18 14:45:16 xen02 kernel: [54277.859540]  ffffffff81076ebe 0000000000000005 ffff8811f5a03e78 ffff8811dee04000
Aug 18 14:45:16 xen02 kernel: [54277.859542]  0000000000000000 ffff8811e4b9c940 0000000000000008 ffffffff81076f3f
Aug 18 14:45:16 xen02 kernel: [54277.859544] Call Trace:
Aug 18 14:45:16 xen02 kernel: [54277.859547]  <IRQ>
Aug 18 14:45:16 xen02 kernel: [54277.859553]  [<ffffffff81328574>] ? dump_stack+0x5c/0x78
Aug 18 14:45:16 xen02 kernel: [54277.859558]  [<ffffffff81076ebe>] ? __warn+0xbe/0xe0
Aug 18 14:45:16 xen02 kernel: [54277.859560]  [<ffffffff81076f3f>] ? warn_slowpath_fmt+0x5f/0x80
Aug 18 14:45:16 xen02 kernel: [54277.859563]  [<ffffffff8152a98d>] ? dev_watchdog+0x22d/0x230
Aug 18 14:45:16 xen02 kernel: [54277.859564]  [<ffffffff8152a760>] ? qdisc_rcu_free+0x40/0x40
Aug 18 14:45:16 xen02 kernel: [54277.859570]  [<ffffffff810e3e90>] ? call_timer_fn+0x30/0x110
Aug 18 14:45:16 xen02 kernel: [54277.859571]  [<ffffffff810e43ce>] ? run_timer_softirq+0x1ce/0x420
Aug 18 14:45:16 xen02 kernel: [54277.859575]  [<ffffffff810d0f91>] ? handle_irq_event_percpu+0x51/0x70
Aug 18 14:45:16 xen02 kernel: [54277.859576]  [<ffffffff810d4dc7>] ? handle_percpu_irq+0x37/0x50
Aug 18 14:45:16 xen02 kernel: [54277.859581]  [<ffffffff81608d95>] ? __do_softirq+0x105/0x290
Aug 18 14:45:16 xen02 kernel: [54277.859583]  [<ffffffff8107cf6e>] ? irq_exit+0xae/0xb0
Aug 18 14:45:16 xen02 kernel: [54277.859587]  [<ffffffff814052e1>] ? xen_evtchn_do_upcall+0x31/0x40
Aug 18 14:45:16 xen02 kernel: [54277.859588]  [<ffffffff8160724e>] ? xen_do_hypervisor_callback+0x1e/0x40
Aug 18 14:45:16 xen02 kernel: [54277.859589]  <EOI>
Aug 18 14:45:16 xen02 kernel: [54277.859592]  [<ffffffff810013aa>] ? xen_hypercall_sched_op+0xa/0x20
Aug 18 14:45:16 xen02 kernel: [54277.859594]  [<ffffffff810013aa>] ? xen_hypercall_sched_op+0xa/0x20
Aug 18 14:45:16 xen02 kernel: [54277.859597]  [<ffffffff8101b30c>] ? xen_safe_halt+0xc/0x20
Aug 18 14:45:16 xen02 kernel: [54277.859600]  [<ffffffff8160584a>] ? default_idle+0x1a/0xd0
Aug 18 14:45:16 xen02 kernel: [54277.859603]  [<ffffffff810b957a>] ? cpu_startup_entry+0x1ca/0x240
Aug 18 14:45:16 xen02 kernel: [54277.859608]  [<ffffffff81d38f57>] ? start_kernel+0x443/0x463
Aug 18 14:45:16 xen02 kernel: [54277.859611]  [<ffffffff81d3e098>] ? xen_start_kernel+0x526/0x530
Aug 18 14:45:16 xen02 kernel: [54277.859613] ---[ end trace 213eed970c44d2fa ]---
Aug 18 14:45:16 xen02 kernel: [54277.859619] bnx2 0000:01:00.1 eno2: <--- start FTQ dump --->
Aug 18 14:45:16 xen02 kernel: [54277.859658] bnx2 0000:01:00.1 eno2: RV2P_PFTQ_CTL 00010000
Aug 18 14:45:16 xen02 kernel: [54277.859682] bnx2 0000:01:00.1 eno2: RV2P_TFTQ_CTL 00020000
Aug 18 14:45:16 xen02 kernel: [54277.859707] bnx2 0000:01:00.1 eno2: RV2P_MFTQ_CTL 00004000
Aug 18 14:45:16 xen02 kernel: [54277.859730] bnx2 0000:01:00.1 eno2: TBDR_FTQ_CTL 00004000
Aug 18 14:45:16 xen02 kernel: [54277.859753] bnx2 0000:01:00.1 eno2: TDMA_FTQ_CTL 00010002
Aug 18 14:45:16 xen02 kernel: [54277.859776] bnx2 0000:01:00.1 eno2: TXP_FTQ_CTL 00010000
Aug 18 14:45:16 xen02 kernel: [54277.859799] bnx2 0000:01:00.1 eno2: TXP_FTQ_CTL 00010000
Aug 18 14:45:16 xen02 kernel: [54277.859822] bnx2 0000:01:00.1 eno2: TPAT_FTQ_CTL 00010000
Aug 18 14:45:16 xen02 kernel: [54277.859845] bnx2 0000:01:00.1 eno2: RXP_CFTQ_CTL 00008000
Aug 18 14:45:16 xen02 kernel: [54277.859868] bnx2 0000:01:00.1 eno2: RXP_FTQ_CTL 00100000
Aug 18 14:45:16 xen02 kernel: [54277.859891] bnx2 0000:01:00.1 eno2: COM_COMXQ_FTQ_CTL 00010000
Aug 18 14:45:16 xen02 kernel: [54277.859916] bnx2 0000:01:00.1 eno2: COM_COMTQ_FTQ_CTL 00020000
Aug 18 14:45:16 xen02 kernel: [54277.859941] bnx2 0000:01:00.1 eno2: COM_COMQ_FTQ_CTL 00010000
Aug 18 14:45:16 xen02 kernel: [54277.859965] bnx2 0000:01:00.1 eno2: CP_CPQ_FTQ_CTL 00004000
Aug 18 14:45:16 xen02 kernel: [54277.859988] bnx2 0000:01:00.1 eno2: CPU states:
Aug 18 14:45:16 xen02 kernel: [54277.860017] bnx2 0000:01:00.1 eno2: 045000 mode b84c state 80001000 evt_mask 500 pc 8001284 pc 8001284 instr 1440fffc
Aug 18 14:45:16 xen02 kernel: [54277.860063] bnx2 0000:01:00.1 eno2: 085000 mode b84c state 80001000 evt_mask 500 pc 8000a4c pc 8000a5c instr 1440fffc
Aug 18 14:45:16 xen02 kernel: [54277.860108] bnx2 0000:01:00.1 eno2: 0c5000 mode b84c state 80001000 evt_mask 500 pc 8004c10 pc 8004c14 instr 32050003
Aug 18 14:45:16 xen02 kernel: [54277.860154] bnx2 0000:01:00.1 eno2: 105000 mode b8cc state 80000000 evt_mask 500 pc 8000a98 pc 8000aa4 instr 3c020800
Aug 18 14:45:16 xen02 kernel: [54277.860199] bnx2 0000:01:00.1 eno2: 145000 mode b880 state 80000000 evt_mask 500 pc 800ae38 pc 800ae40 instr 24130001
Aug 18 14:45:16 xen02 kernel: [54277.860245] bnx2 0000:01:00.1 eno2: 185000 mode b8cc state 80000000 evt_mask 500 pc 8000c6c pc 8000c6c instr 1180000b
Aug 18 14:45:16 xen02 kernel: [54277.860285] bnx2 0000:01:00.1 eno2: <--- end FTQ dump --->
Aug 18 14:45:16 xen02 kernel: [54277.860308] bnx2 0000:01:00.1 eno2: <--- start TBDC dump --->
Aug 18 14:45:16 xen02 kernel: [54277.860332] bnx2 0000:01:00.1 eno2: TBDC free cnt: 32
Aug 18 14:45:16 xen02 kernel: [54277.860353] bnx2 0000:01:00.1 eno2: LINE     CID  BIDX   CMD  VALIDS
Aug 18 14:45:16 xen02 kernel: [54277.860382] bnx2 0000:01:00.1 eno2: 00    001100  d618   00    [0]
Aug 18 14:45:16 xen02 kernel: [54277.860411] bnx2 0000:01:00.1 eno2: 01    001300  61b8   00    [0]
Aug 18 14:45:16 xen02 kernel: [54277.860440] bnx2 0000:01:00.1 eno2: 02    001280  63c8   00    [0]
Aug 18 14:45:16 xen02 kernel: [54277.860469] bnx2 0000:01:00.1 eno2: 03    000800  79c8   00    [0]
Aug 18 14:45:16 xen02 kernel: [54277.860498] bnx2 0000:01:00.1 eno2: 04    000800  40f8   00    [0]
Aug 18 14:45:16 xen02 kernel: [54277.860526] bnx2 0000:01:00.1 eno2: 05    16fd80  9ef8   bf    [0]
Aug 18 14:45:16 xen02 kernel: [54277.860555] bnx2 0000:01:00.1 eno2: 06    1b5f80  f7c8   7f    [0]
Aug 18 14:45:16 xen02 kernel: [54277.860584] bnx2 0000:01:00.1 eno2: 07    1bef80  fbd8   7f    [0]
Aug 18 14:45:16 xen02 kernel: [54277.860612] bnx2 0000:01:00.1 eno2: 08    1bcd80  f5f8   7c    [0]
Aug 18 14:45:16 xen02 kernel: [54277.860641] bnx2 0000:01:00.1 eno2: 09    1fff80  f9f8   96    [0]
Aug 18 14:45:16 xen02 kernel: [54277.860669] bnx2 0000:01:00.1 eno2: 0a    077f00  e7b8   7f    [0]
Aug 18 14:45:16 xen02 kernel: [54277.860698] bnx2 0000:01:00.1 eno2: 0b    1dff80  f9f8   e7    [0]
Aug 18 14:45:16 xen02 kernel: [54277.860727] bnx2 0000:01:00.1 eno2: 0c    1f9c00  7a78   f0    [0]
Aug 18 14:45:16 xen02 kernel: [54277.860756] bnx2 0000:01:00.1 eno2: 0d    0ff680  fdf8   ff    [0]
Aug 18 14:45:16 xen02 kernel: [54277.860784] bnx2 0000:01:00.1 eno2: 0e    067980  ffe8   f7    [0]
Aug 18 14:45:16 xen02 kernel: [54277.860813] bnx2 0000:01:00.1 eno2: 0f    0ef300  fb78   7e    [0]
Aug 18 14:45:16 xen02 kernel: [54277.860842] bnx2 0000:01:00.1 eno2: 10    1be600  dff8   df    [0]
Aug 18 14:45:16 xen02 kernel: [54277.860870] bnx2 0000:01:00.1 eno2: 11    1fff80  faf8   bf    [0]
Aug 18 14:45:16 xen02 kernel: [54277.860899] bnx2 0000:01:00.1 eno2: 12    05fd80  7ef8   ff    [0]
Aug 18 14:45:16 xen02 kernel: [54277.860928] bnx2 0000:01:00.1 eno2: 13    1fba00  d6f0   ff    [0]
Aug 18 14:45:16 xen02 kernel: [54277.860957] bnx2 0000:01:00.1 eno2: 14    1fed80  7fd8   db    [0]
Aug 18 14:45:16 xen02 kernel: [54277.860985] bnx2 0000:01:00.1 eno2: 15    17cf80  73b0   dd    [0]
Aug 18 14:45:16 xen02 kernel: [54277.861014] bnx2 0000:01:00.1 eno2: 16    1ff700  eff8   1b    [0]
Aug 18 14:45:16 xen02 kernel: [54277.861042] bnx2 0000:01:00.1 eno2: 17    1dfd80  eeb8   7f    [0]
Aug 18 14:45:16 xen02 kernel: [54277.861071] bnx2 0000:01:00.1 eno2: 18    1bd780  fff8   ff    [0]
Aug 18 14:45:16 xen02 kernel: [54277.861099] bnx2 0000:01:00.1 eno2: 19    17fb80  fef0   df    [0]
Aug 18 14:45:16 xen02 kernel: [54277.861128] bnx2 0000:01:00.1 eno2: 1a    1ffe80  6a70   df    [0]
Aug 18 14:45:16 xen02 kernel: [54277.861157] bnx2 0000:01:00.1 eno2: 1b    1efe80  dfe8   ff    [0]
Aug 18 14:45:16 xen02 kernel: [54277.861186] bnx2 0000:01:00.1 eno2: 1c    0f7f80  dfb0   7f    [0]
Aug 18 14:45:16 xen02 kernel: [54277.861214] bnx2 0000:01:00.1 eno2: 1d    1f7f80  fad8   fb    [0]
Aug 18 14:45:16 xen02 kernel: [54277.861243] bnx2 0000:01:00.1 eno2: 1e    1fff80  fbd8   d7    [0]
Aug 18 14:45:16 xen02 kernel: [54277.861272] bnx2 0000:01:00.1 eno2: 1f    0bbf80  ffd8   bb    [0]
Aug 18 14:45:16 xen02 kernel: [54277.861297] bnx2 0000:01:00.1 eno2: <--- end TBDC dump --->
Aug 18 14:45:16 xen02 kernel: [54277.861327] bnx2 0000:01:00.1 eno2: DEBUG: intr_sem[0] PCI_CMD[00100406]
Aug 18 14:45:16 xen02 kernel: [54277.861358] bnx2 0000:01:00.1 eno2: DEBUG: PCI_PM[19002008] PCI_MISC_CFG[92000088]
Aug 18 14:45:16 xen02 kernel: [54277.861851] bnx2 0000:01:00.1 eno2: DEBUG: EMAC_TX_STATUS[00000008] EMAC_RX_STATUS[00000000]
Aug 18 14:45:16 xen02 kernel: [54277.862318] bnx2 0000:01:00.1 eno2: DEBUG: RPM_MGMT_PKT_CTRL[40000088]
Aug 18 14:45:16 xen02 kernel: [54277.862770] bnx2 0000:01:00.1 eno2: DEBUG: HC_STATS_INTERRUPT_STATUS[01df0020]
Aug 18 14:45:16 xen02 kernel: [54277.863211] bnx2 0000:01:00.1 eno2: DEBUG: PBA[00000000]
Aug 18 14:45:16 xen02 kernel: [54277.863653] bnx2 0000:01:00.1 eno2: <--- start MCP states dump --->
Aug 18 14:45:16 xen02 kernel: [54277.864102] bnx2 0000:01:00.1 eno2: DEBUG: MCP_STATE_P0[0003610e] MCP_STATE_P1[0003610e]
Aug 18 14:45:16 xen02 kernel: [54277.864570] bnx2 0000:01:00.1 eno2: DEBUG: MCP mode[0000b880] state[80008000] evt_mask[00000500]
Aug 18 14:45:16 xen02 kernel: [54277.865039] bnx2 0000:01:00.1 eno2: DEBUG: pc[080009b8] pc[0800d240] instr[1440002c]
Aug 18 14:45:16 xen02 kernel: [54277.865515] bnx2 0000:01:00.1 eno2: DEBUG: shmem states:
Aug 18 14:45:16 xen02 kernel: [54277.865993] bnx2 0000:01:00.1 eno2: DEBUG: drv_mb[01030003] fw_mb[00000003] link_status[0000006e]
Aug 18 14:45:16 xen02 kernel: [54277.866494]  drv_pulse_mb[00004ed3]
Aug 18 14:45:16 xen02 kernel: [54277.866498] bnx2 0000:01:00.1 eno2: DEBUG: dev_info_signature[44564903] reset_type[01005254]
Aug 18 14:45:16 xen02 kernel: [54277.867006]  condition[0003610e]
Aug 18 14:45:16 xen02 kernel: [54277.867012] bnx2 0000:01:00.1 eno2: DEBUG: 000001c0: 01005254 42530000 0003610e 00000000
Aug 18 14:45:16 xen02 kernel: [54277.867565] bnx2 0000:01:00.1 eno2: DEBUG: 000003cc: 44444444 44444444 44444444 00000a28
Aug 18 14:45:16 xen02 kernel: [54277.868094] bnx2 0000:01:00.1 eno2: DEBUG: 000003dc: 0004ffff 00000000 00000000 00000000
Aug 18 14:45:16 xen02 kernel: [54277.868638] bnx2 0000:01:00.1 eno2: DEBUG: 000003ec: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
Aug 18 14:45:16 xen02 kernel: [54277.869161] bnx2 0000:01:00.1 eno2: DEBUG: 0x3fc[0000ffff]
Aug 18 14:45:16 xen02 kernel: [54277.869686] bnx2 0000:01:00.1 eno2: <--- end MCP states dump --->
Aug 18 14:45:16 xen02 kernel: [54277.952626] bnx2 0000:01:00.1 eno2: NIC Copper Link is Down
Aug 18 14:45:16 xen02 kernel: [54277.953376] br-eno2: port 1(eno2) entered disabled state
Aug 18 14:45:19 xen02 kernel: [54281.121380] bnx2 0000:01:00.1 eno2: NIC Copper Link is Up, 1000 Mbps full duplex
Aug 18 14:45:19 xen02 kernel: [54281.121395] , receive & transmit flow control ON
Aug 18 14:45:19 xen02 kernel: [54281.121506] br-eno2: port 1(eno2) entered blocking state
Aug 18 14:45:19 xen02 kernel: [54281.121518] br-eno2: port 1(eno2) entered forwarding state
Aug 18 14:45:21 xen02 kernel: [54282.291106] bnx2 0000:01:00.1 eno2: NIC Copper Link is Down
Aug 18 14:45:21 xen02 kernel: [54282.292209] br-eno2: port 1(eno2) entered disabled state
Aug 18 14:45:23 xen02 kernel: [54284.644260] bnx2 0000:01:00.1 eno2: NIC Copper Link is Up, 1000 Mbps full duplex
Aug 18 14:45:23 xen02 kernel: [54284.644275] , receive & transmit flow control ON
Aug 18 14:45:23 xen02 kernel: [54284.644373] br-eno2: port 1(eno2) entered blocking state
Aug 18 14:45:23 xen02 kernel: [54284.644386] br-eno2: port 1(eno2) entered forwarding state
Aug 18 14:45:31 xen02 kernel: [54292.350727] usb 6-3: reset high-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
Aug 18 14:45:47 xen02 kernel: [54308.549804] usb 6-3: device not accepting address 4, error -110
Aug 18 14:45:47 xen02 kernel: [54308.669880] usb 6-3: reset high-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
Aug 18 14:46:03 xen02 kernel: [54324.676957] usb 6-3: device not accepting address 4, error -110
Aug 18 14:46:03 xen02 kernel: [54324.796936] usb 6-3: reset high-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
Aug 18 14:46:10 xen02 kernel: [54331.872538] bnx2 0000:01:00.1 eno2: <--- start FTQ dump --->
Aug 18 14:46:10 xen02 kernel: [54331.873570] bnx2 0000:01:00.1 eno2: RV2P_PFTQ_CTL 00010000
Aug 18 14:46:10 xen02 kernel: [54331.874207] bnx2 0000:01:00.1 eno2: RV2P_TFTQ_CTL 00020000
Aug 18 14:46:10 xen02 kernel: [54331.874793] bnx2 0000:01:00.1 eno2: RV2P_MFTQ_CTL 00004000
Aug 18 14:46:10 xen02 kernel: [54331.875336] bnx2 0000:01:00.1 eno2: TBDR_FTQ_CTL 00004002
Aug 18 14:46:10 xen02 kernel: [54331.875876] bnx2 0000:01:00.1 eno2: TDMA_FTQ_CTL 00010000
Aug 18 14:46:10 xen02 kernel: [54331.876408] bnx2 0000:01:00.1 eno2: TXP_FTQ_CTL 00010000
Aug 18 14:46:10 xen02 kernel: [54331.876953] bnx2 0000:01:00.1 eno2: TXP_FTQ_CTL 00010000
Aug 18 14:46:10 xen02 kernel: [54331.877475] bnx2 0000:01:00.1 eno2: TPAT_FTQ_CTL 00010000
Aug 18 14:46:10 xen02 kernel: [54331.877999] bnx2 0000:01:00.1 eno2: RXP_CFTQ_CTL 00008000
Aug 18 14:46:10 xen02 kernel: [54331.878524] bnx2 0000:01:00.1 eno2: RXP_FTQ_CTL 00100000
Aug 18 14:46:10 xen02 kernel: [54331.879061] bnx2 0000:01:00.1 eno2: COM_COMXQ_FTQ_CTL 00010000
Aug 18 14:46:10 xen02 kernel: [54331.879595] bnx2 0000:01:00.1 eno2: COM_COMTQ_FTQ_CTL 00020000
Aug 18 14:46:10 xen02 kernel: [54331.880129] bnx2 0000:01:00.1 eno2: COM_COMQ_FTQ_CTL 00010000
Aug 18 14:46:10 xen02 kernel: [54331.880673] bnx2 0000:01:00.1 eno2: CP_CPQ_FTQ_CTL 00004000
Aug 18 14:46:10 xen02 kernel: [54331.881209] bnx2 0000:01:00.1 eno2: CPU states:
Aug 18 14:46:10 xen02 kernel: [54331.881754] bnx2 0000:01:00.1 eno2: 045000 mode b84c state 80001000 evt_mask 500 pc 8001294 pc 8001284 instr 8e260000
Aug 18 14:46:10 xen02 kernel: [54331.882330] bnx2 0000:01:00.1 eno2: 085000 mode b84c state 80005000 evt_mask 500 pc 8000a4c pc 8000a4c instr 10400016
Aug 18 14:46:10 xen02 kernel: [54331.882917] bnx2 0000:01:00.1 eno2: 0c5000 mode b84c state 80001000 evt_mask 500 pc 8004c20 pc 8004c14 instr 10e00088
Aug 18 14:46:10 xen02 kernel: [54331.883497] bnx2 0000:01:00.1 eno2: 105000 mode b8cc state 80000000 evt_mask 500 pc 8000aa4 pc 8000b28 instr 3c028000
Aug 18 14:46:10 xen02 kernel: [54331.884088] bnx2 0000:01:00.1 eno2: 145000 mode b880 state 80004000 evt_mask 500 pc 800adec pc 800ae00 instr 8c6366e4
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

update 20170926 - Have updated second machine with 2 dual port intel nic cards and disabled bnx2 and machine still continues to crash. Without any domU's, the first machine has remained up for 6days.

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact issue and am convinced the flaky chipset is to blame.  See below for background details.

**Workaround**: Limit and Pin your Dom0 to use only 1 or 2 CPU cores, as suggested in https://wiki.debian.org/Xen#Other_configuration_tweaks and https://wiki.xenproject.org/wiki/Tuning_Xen_for_Performance

**Workaround steps**:

1: In /etc/default/grub, add/modify GRUB_CMDLINE_XEN to contain:

`GRUB_CMDLINE_XEN="dom0_max_vcpus=1 dom0_vcpus_pin"`

(On my Dom0, I limit the memory as well with: *dom0_mem=2048M* and turn off autobalooning)

2: run `update-grub` to update the bootloader

3: In your DomU */etc/xen/ .cfg* files, add the following to each DomU to keep it off CPU 0:

`cpus="all,^0"`

(or if you limited to 2 cores, use:  `cpus="all,^0-1"` )

4: Shut down your DomU's and reboot to get the new kernel settings.  Your Dom0 should now have only one VCPU showing in `top` output

5: Reset the "days since last kernel panic" sign on your wall and cross your fingers!

***Background:***

A sad story!  This started happening to me immediately after upgrading a busy DomU to a new PowerEdge R710 Dom0.  It was absolutely brutal troubleshooting it!  It happened with just one DomU running on the box (so having 24 VM's is not your root cause).   Nothing worked to stop or fix it, it would trigger at busy times, and the error would change back and forth from the "transmit queue timed out" to errors with the RAID controller going read-only.  I tried everything on your list including switching to Intel e1000 NIC's and a new physical R710 chassis.  I fiddled in vain with the BIOS trying to get the NIC and RAID on a seperate IRQ.  For a week the server blew up multiple times a day with important prod sites on it.  It was truly horrible in every way :(

Finally, I found some relief by following suggestions at the end of this bug here: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=866952.  While it wasn't our bug description at all (it was Dom0 won't boot), it was current, Xen, and a R710.  It recommends reducing and pinning Dom0 CPUS as per https://wiki.xenproject.org/wiki/Tuning_Xen_for_Performance.

Desperate for anything to try, I tried it, and (ZOMG!) it worked! Limiting the Dom0 to just use two CPU's, and pinning the DomUs to use only the other cores, made the problem go away for me and stay gone for 2+ months.  I was actually sure this solved the problem completely, but then I had the error recur last week.  I'm going to try going down to just 1 pinned CPU for the Dom0 next.

I am convinced the issue is the interrupt handling being flailed by the Intel chipset, and none of the workarounds we found online work.  That's because they are all from many years ago.

Answer (score 0):

Not in an R710, but I have seen this with other onboard Broadcoms, it was always a defective NIC, I suspect you will need to either add a plug-in NIC or do without it.

You can verify this by booting from a plain vanilla (non-XEN) USB stick and saturate the NIC (e.g. with a few `netcat`s) - you will most likely see some error messages concerning bus errors just before the crash.